# Нужно ли использовать try catch для отправки emails в очередях?

Tags: laravel

```
public function send(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {

        try {

            $job = new SendEmailJob($request->validated());

            dispatch($job)->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));

        }catch (\Exception $e){

            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Messages not sent!',
            ], $e->getCode());

        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Messages sent successfully!'
        ],200);

    }
```

Comment: А какую логику вы пытаетесь реализовать? Вы сами должны на свой вопрос ответить

Comment: Обычно в очередях обработку критических ошибок не делают. Потому что у очереди есть собственная политика обработки ошибок. Если задача в очереди завершается неудачно, то она может быть автоматически перезапущена. Причём перезапуск может быть с задержкой во времени

Comment: #nomnoms12 ну к примеру я только что поменял название БД ошибку отловил

Вы считаете просто всегда возвращать 200 один return и все?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#error-handling - тут ясно написано, как обрабатываются ошибки задач при их выполнении. try ... catch в этом коде вообще ничего не отловит - смотрите определение dispatch() - там никакие ошибки не бросаются в принципе.